# Best practice linking back to source view

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have several views that show a detail with an edit button. When the user clicks on the edit button, they go to the edit view for that item. From the edit view I want to link back to the original view. What is a best practice people use so the edit view knows where to take the user back to?

I am using PHP with the Laravel framework.

Example:

User on /invoice/1/detail, click on edit to /contact/9/edit, click on save or cancel, go back to /invoice/1/detail

Or

User on /task/2/detail, click on edit to /contact/9/edit, click on save or cancel, go back to /task/2/detail

Or

User on /report/3/detail, click on edit to /contact/9/edit, click on save or cancel, go back to /report/3/detail

Comment: I am not using RESTful routing.  It doesn't look like that would be my answer, but I may be missing something.

What I am looking for would be something like this:

User on /invoice/1/detail, click on edit to /contact/9/edit, click on save or cancel, go back to /invoice/1/detail

or

User on /task/2/detail, click on edit to /contact/9/edit, click on save or cancel, go back to /task/2/detail

Answer (score 0):

You would definitely benefit from Resource Controllers (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) if you're willing to take the plunge. After adopting those, your detail views would all look

```
public function show($id) {...}
```

and your edit views would all look like

```
public function edit($id) {...}
```

and the routing would more or less handle itself.

Assuming you've adopted this convention, you can put some common logic in a base controller and have your individual controllers extend them.

A base controller could have stuff like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as Controller;

class BaseController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Returns the routable action string for editing this resource
     * @return string
     */
    final protected function getEditAction()
    {
        return __CLASS__ . '@edit';
    }

    /**
     * Returns the routable action string for showing this resource
     * @return string
     */
    final protected function getShowAction()
    {
        return __CLASS__ . '@show';
    }
}
```

Then, from a controller extending your base controller, you could do stuff like this:

```
// Redirect to the detail page upon save
return Redirect::action($this->getShowAction());

// Pass a link to the detail page into a view
return View::make('foo.bar', ['back_url' => URL::action($this->getShowAction())]);
```

And so on.

Comment: Thanks.  Using GET parameters is how i'm doing it.  Looking for ideas if there are better ways.